# Filtering dropdown queryset based on URL parameter

Tags: django, forms

I am building a CRM where I want each client to have multiple plans, and each plan to have multiple notes. When a user creates a new note, I want them to be able to select a relevant plan from a dropdown of plans belonging to the client. From what I can find, I should be able to get the contact_id from the kwargs, but my errors show nothing in kwargs. I know there should be a way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

```
Variable    Value
__class__   <class 'lynx.forms.SipNoteForm'>
args    ()
kwargs  {}
self    <SipNoteForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(sip_plan;note;note_date;fiscal_year;quarter;class_hours;instructor;clients)>
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def add_sip_note(request, contact_id):
    form = SipNoteForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SipNoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.contact_id = contact_id
            form.user_id = request.user.id
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('lynx:client', args=(contact_id,)))
    return render(request, 'lynx/add_sip_note.html', {'form': form})
```

Forms.py

```
class SipNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SipNote
        exclude = ('created', 'modified', 'user', 'contact')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SipNoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sip_plan'].queryset = SipPlan.objects.filter(contact_id=kwargs.get("contact_id"))
```

Urls.py

```
path('add-sip-note/<int:contact_id>/', views.add_sip_note, name='add_sip_note'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `kwargs` in `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` as

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        contact_id = kwargs.pop('contact_id')
        super(SipNoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sip_plan'].queryset = SipPlan.objects.filter(contact_id=contact_id)
```

But you are not passing `contact_id` `kwargs` to the form while posting. you should pass `kwargs` to the form you are going to get in `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` such as

```
@login_required
def add_sip_note(request, contact_id):
    form = SipNoteForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SipNoteForm(request.POST, contact_id=contact_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated my code to include ```form = SipNoteForm(request.POST, contact_id=contact_id)```, but I think I also need it when I definte form earlier, in ```form = SipNoteForm()```. I tried ```form = SipNoteForm(contact_id=contact_id)```, ```form = SipNoteForm(None, contact_id=contact_id)``` and ```form = SipNoteForm(request, contact_id=contact_id)``` but all of those gave me the same error
```__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'contact_id' ```

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, I wrote my view initiation like

```contact = {'contact_id': contact_id}
form = SipNoteForm(**contact)```

And in my forms, I popped contact_id out of the kwargs before the ```__init__```, so 

```def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        contact_id = kwargs.pop('contact_id')

        super(SipNoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['sip_plan'].queryset = SipPlan.objects.filter(contact_id=contact_id)```

Thank you for your help, I was really stuck!